# Maximizing expression under assumption that similar expression is maximized.

Tags: analysis, optimization, induction

I'm trying to maximize the following expression:
$$
\left(\frac{a_{2}}{4^{k_{1}}}-4 a_{2}^{3}\right) \cdot 1+\sum_{j=2}^{m}\left(\frac{a_{j+1}}{4^{k_{j}}}-4 a_{j+1}^{3}\right) \prod_{i=2}^{j}\left(\frac{4^{k_{i}}}{4^{k_{i-1}}}-1\right)
$$
where $k_i$ is a positive integer such that $a_i \in (2^{-k_i-1}, 2^{-k_i}]$ for $i = 1,...,m$. We can assume that $a_i \in [0,1]$ and that the values are decreasing i.e if $a_i \in (2^{-k_i-1}, 2^{-k_i}]$ then $a_{i+1} \leq 2^{-k_i-1}$. Based on some experimentation I have a strong suspicion that the expression is maximized
for $a_{i+1}=1 / 2^{k_{i}+2}$.

I figured that induction
and local optimality will probably do the trick: Assume the result for limited
$i$, apply the assumption, then optimize the terms with $i+1$ under the assumption
that the smaller terms must also be chosen optimally wrt each other. However, I can't really get anywhere with this.

It is stated in [this](https://publikationsserver.tu-braunschweig.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/dbbs_derivate_00008754/Diss-Schweer.pdf) [Page 63] that a similar expression, namely
$$
\left(\frac{a_{2}}{2^{k_{1}}}-2 a_{2}^{2}\right) \cdot 1+\sum_{j=2}^{m}\left(\frac{a_{j+1}}{2^{k_{j}}}-2 a_{j+1}^{2}\right) \prod_{i=2}^{j}\left(\frac{2^{k_{i}}}{2^{k_{i-1}}}-1\right)
$$
where $a_i$ is subject to the same constraints is maximized if indeed we choose $a_{i+1}=1 / 2^{k_{i}+2}$, for $i=1, \ldots, m$, i.e., $k_{i}=k_{1}+2(i-1)$.

So. Any help with a solution from the scratch would be greatly appreciated or alternatively, a solution using the result of the second expression would be more than sufficient.

Edit: The $k_i$'s are determined by the $a_i$'s (as it should show in the second line). Providing some more context $2^{-k_i}$ is the smallest number greater than or equal to $a_i$ or alternatively $a_i$ is the side length of a square and we round $a_i$ up to the closest power of 1/2.

Comment: Is there any assumption that the sequence of $k_i$'s is nondecreasing?

Comment: @Voliar - yes thanks. I'll update the question accordingly as well to reflect this. In fact I think strictly increasing is fine too.

Comment: are $k_i$ also variables? Then, you should emphasize that otherwise it reads like $k_i$ are fixed.

Comment: The $k_i$'s are determined by the $a_i$'s. Because the $a_i$'s are strictly decreasing it follows that the $k_i$'s are strictly increasing. That is at least what it is meant to say with the last update. @dezdichado . Provding some more context $2^{-k_i}$ is the smallest number greater than or equal to $a_i$ or alternatively $a_i$ is the side length of a square and we round $a_i$ up to the closest power of 1/2.

Comment: Then where is the formula that gives $k_i$ given $a_i$ ? You mention $a_i$ subject to constraints, which makes it sound like $k_i$ are given constants i.e, the function you are optimizing is of the form $F(a_1,a_2,\dots a_n)$. But then in the end, you also mention the maximum happens at particular values of $k_i$, with no mention whatsover about $k_1.$ 

This is a very poorly worded problem and I'd recommend you make the language precise if you want to get people's attention.

Comment: @dezdichado - I'm not sure I understand the problem, but I'll be more than happy to rephrase the question when I do. 

The problem is essentially that we're given a sequence of squares $(a_1, a_2,...a_n)$ and these squares have to be placed in some larger boxes and of course a box needs to be able to fit a square so we round the side length of the square $a_i$ up to the nearest power of $1/2$ to determine the smallest box in which the square will fit. In this way, there is only one value of $k_i$ you are allowed to choose for $a_i$.

Comment: I see - I glanced at the text and am rather reluctant to read the context. But the algebra part seems obvious. In the below configuration, each individual term is quadratic and is maximized at where it's derivative is equal to zero. Hence, you get $\dfrac{1}{2^{k_j}}-4a_{j+1} = 0$ or $a_{j+1} = 2^{-{k_j-2}}.$ I suspect you just do the same for your own version, which does not quite give the same answer as you hypothesized. You just maximize the individual cubic term and be done with it it look like.

Comment: Edited: Okay yes, that seems to fit what they've done. However this last term that's multiplied will be large if $k_{i-1}$ is a lot smaller than $k_i$. What is the argument that we can disregard this part? I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I will just write it as an answer here. First, the term $\left(\dfrac{a_{j+1}}{2^{k_j}} - 2a_{j+1}^2\right)$ is a quadratic (an upside down paraboloa) which is easily maximized at $a_{j+1} = 2^{-k_j-2}.$

Then you plug this value into the expression and the $j$-th summand is:
$$2^{-2k_j-3}\prod_{i=2}^j(2^{k_i-k_{i-1}}-1) \quad (1).$$

This grows without a bound in general; however, this problem has the restriction $$2^{-k_{j+1}-1}\le a_{j+1}\leq 2^{-k_{j+1}}$$
and we want $a_{j+1} = 2^{-k_j-2}.$ This necessarily implies
$$k_{j+1}\leq k_j+2\leq k_{j+1}+1 \iff 1\leq k_{j+1}-k_j\leq 2.$$
Now obviously, choosing $k_{j+1}- k_j = 2$ maximizes $(1)$ and that concludes the logic of the claim in your textbook.

For your own version, you should be able to do exactly the same thing.